# Finding $a$ such that $\{1 + ax, a + (a+2)x\}$ are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find a value of $a$ such that $\{1 + ax, a + (a+2)x\}$ are linearly dependent. I know I need to find a value $a$ such that one vector is a multiple of the other, but I'm having trouble going about it.

Comment: Or they are just polynomials?

Comment: and a is a vector? :)

Comment: It does make sense, it seems he's working with the space of polynomials

Comment: Yes, polynomials!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then $1\cdot k=a$ and $a\cdot k=a+2 \to a^2=a+2\to a=2$ or $a=-1$

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more please?

Comment: No wait. Perfect. Thanks